# WHERE followed by ON clause

Tags: mysql, sql, presto, trino

What is the semantic difference between the following queries? To me both seemed similar until I executed them on presto. Is this something specific to presto or am I missing something in the SQL standard?

Form 1: All conditions specified in the ON clause.

```
SELECT
    t1.colA,
    t1.colB,
    t1.colC,
    t2.colD
FROM t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2
    ON t1.colA = t2.colA
    AND t1.colB = t2.colB
    AND t1.colE = 1
    AND t2.colF = 2;
```

Form 2: Some conditions specified in the WHERE clause instead.

```
SELECT
    t1.colA,
    t1.colB,
    t1.colC,
    t2.colD
FROM t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2
    ON t1.colA = t2.colA
    AND t1.colB = t2.colB
WHERE
    t1.colE = 1
    AND t2.colF = 2;
```

Form 1 results in some rows but form 2 doesn't but shouldn't they be equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two important differences.

First the condition `t1.colE = 1`.  A `LEFT JOIN` keeps all rows in the first table, regardless of what the `ON` clause evaluates to.  So, `t1.colE` does not change the number of rows in the result set.  However, it does have the strange effect that any columns from `t2` when this condition is not true are `NULL`.

Second the condition `t2.colF = 2` has a different effect.  This turns the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`, because `NULL` values do not match the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` and `WHERE` clause that references the `right_table`, it is equivalent to an `[INNER] JOIN`. That is, the following two are equivalent:

```
-- [inner] join
select ...
from left_table
join right_table 
  on left_table.cola = right_table.cola 
 and right_table.colb = 2

-- left [outer] join + where
select ...
from left_table
left join right_table
       on left_table.cola = right_table.cola
where right_table.colb = 2
```

Your 2nd example query has a `left join` and this condition `t2.colF = 2` in the `where` clause, making it different from the first query.

where the the first includes all rows from `t1`, the second includes only rows where `t1.colE = 1` and `t2.colF = 2`

Answer (score 0):

The way to think about the difference between the `WHERE` clause and the `ON` clause is:

- The `WHERE` clause determines which of the rows produced by the `FROM` clause should be considered in the query, so it's role is to filter rows before they get processed by a `GROUP BY`, `WINDOW` or the `SELECT` clause.
- The `ON` clause determines whether a pair of rows from the left and right side of a `JOIN` should be considered for the join operation.

  - For an `INNER JOIN`, if the `ON` clause evaluates to false, the rows are not joined with each other and no result is emitted.
  - For a `LEFT JOIN`, if, for a given row on the left side the `ON` clause evaluates to false for all rows on the right side, a row containing the values from the left side and NULLs for the columns on the right side is emitted. The same logic applies for a `RIGHT JOIN`, but with the sides reversed.
  - A `FULL JOIN` is a combination of `LEFT` and `RIGHT` joins.

In your example, the second query, any row produced by the `LEFT JOIN` that contains NULLs in columns from the right side due to the `ON` clause evaluating to `false` will be filtered out by the `t2.colF = 2` expression `WHERE` clause.